# Reactjs and typescript error TS2322: Type is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have run into a TS2322 error while passing the method searchForBooks as props to SearchBooks component from the JumboBooks component:

JumboBooks.tsx (Parent)

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
...
export class JumboBooks extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
...
searchForBooks(searchFilters: SearchParameters){...}    
...

 public render() {
        return (
            <div>
<SearchBooks searchForBooks={this.searchForBooks} />
...
}
```

SearchBooks.tsx

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
...
interface IBookSearchProps {
    searchForBooks:(filters: SearchParameters)=> void; 
}

export class SearchBooks extends React.Component<IBookSearchProps & RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
isearchForBooks() {
    var filters: SearchParameters = {
        // fill up parameters based on ref values
    };

    this.props.searchForBooks(filters);
  }
  ...
}

export interface SearchParameters
{
    ...
}
```

Error:

> Error:
>       TS2322: Type '{ searchForBooks: (searchFilters: SearchParameters) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>...'.
>             Type '{ searchForBooks: (searchFilters: SearchParameters) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly>'.
>               Property 'match' is missing in type '{ searchForBooks: (searchFilters: SearchParameters) => void; }'.

Comment: `RouteComponentProps` is adding a necessary `match` prop to your `SearchBooks` component, but it's not being provided. Does that come from a HOC later on?

Comment: @RossAllen I have this import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router'; statement for both.

Comment: @John Right, but the type complaint is that when you're instantiating `SearchBooks` like this: `<SearchBooks searchForBooks={this.searchForBooks} />`, it's not getting the `match` prop that you said it needed when you did `& RouteComponentProps<{}>`. Where does that `match` prop come from? Is this component wrapped in a higher-order component?

Comment: @RossAllen You've nailed it! Could you please let me know how to pass  the match prop? As an answer to this question instead in this comment.

Comment: @John I don't know how to pass the `match` prop. Where do you expect it to come from? Which component is actually being used as a `'react-router'` Route? You will have to pass the prop down normally.

Comment: @RossAllen I'm quite new to this, could you please suggest the best way to go about it?

Comment: Which component are you using when you're rendering `<Route component={...} />`? Is that your `JumboBooks` component?

Comment: @RossAllen Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only your `JumboBooks` is actually being using as a RouteComponent (being passed as `<Route component={JumboBooks} />`), so only it will automatically receive the `match` prop. Any descendants of `JumboBooks` that you want to have access to `match` you will have to pass in like a normal old prop:

```
export class JumboBooks extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBooks
          match={this.props.match}
          searchForBooks={this.searchForBooks}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

if you don't actually need the `match` prop, delete the `RouteComponentProps<{}>` from your `SearchBooks` component:

```
export class SearchBooks extends React.Component<IBookSearchProps, {}> {
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked when I added: <SearchBooks history={this.props.history} location={this.props.location} match={this.props.match} searchForBooks={this.searchForBooks} />